# Recalculating column width with DataTables.net

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10

I'm using DataTables.net for a table that gets its data using Ajax calls back to the server. The table is in a Bootstrap v4.3.1 tab, so it is not initially visible when the page loads. I've found that when this is the case the column widths do not calculate correctly - they are all of equal width.

My solution to this is to handle the "shown.bs.tab" event on the tab, to identify when my table's tab is selected. At this point I'd like to force it to re-calculate the column widths.

According to the [DataTables.net documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) I should be calling $('#myTable').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(); within my event handler to recalculate the column widths. On the surface of it, this does indeed recalculate the column widths, but has the unfortunate side-effect of fetching a fresh dataset from the server each time - something I'd rather avoid.

Is there any way of resizing the columns in JavaScript **WITHOUT** fetching a fresh set of data?

```js
$('#myTable').DataTable({
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "/api/myTable",
  "sServerMethod": "POST",
  "cache": false,
  "columns": [
   { "data": "ActivityAt", "width": "10%" },
   { "data": "ActivityBy", "width": "20%" },
   { "data": "ActivityType", "width": "10%" },
   { "data": "Text", "width": "60%" },
  ]
 });
   
$('.nav-tabs a')
 .off('shown.bs.tab')    // Remove any existing event handlers for this event
 .on('shown.bs.tab',     // When the tab has been shown...
  function (e) {   
   $('#myTable').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
  });
```

```html
<!-- Tabstrip Header -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-3" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tabSummary" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><h6>Summary</h6></a>
    </li>
    <!-- Other tabs snipped -->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tabMyTable" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><h6>My Table</h6></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tabstrip Content -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="p-3 tab-pane fade show active" id="tabSummary">
    Summary 
  </div>
  <!-- Other tabs snipped -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="p-3 tab-pane fade show active" id="tabMyTable">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-sm mb-0 w-100" style="max-height: 50vh; overflow-y: auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Activity At</th>
                    <th>Activity By</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work to save `$('#myTable').DataTable({//stuff})` to a variable and then call `myVar.columns.adjust().draw()` ?

Comment: Alas, this still causes the datatable to request an updated dataset from the server

Comment: Maybe `columns.adjust()`?  https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Could you please submit this as an answer rather than a comment so as I can mark it as such? Cheers!